# Convert 32 bit dynamic library to 64 bit for osx

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, 32bit-64bit, dynamic-library, libtool-xcode

How to compile existing dynamic library to 64 bit compatible for mac platform. I don't have code base for library, have only xxx.dylib.

file xxx.dylib

xxx.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [ppc:Mach-O dynamically linked shared library ppc] [i386:Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386]
xxx.dylib (for architecture ppc):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library ppc
xxx.dylib (for architecture i386):  Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't.** There's no way to recompile the dylib to 64bit without the original source code.

Worse, even some crazy binary post processing is not really feasible.

The dylib is in `Mach-o` final fat binary executable format. The main challenges are:

- 32bit x86 intel opcodes in `i386` slice - you can't effortlessly convert those to `x86-64`, this would be effectively a different binary
- most likely `0x1000` origin of virtual memory for `__TEXT` start (that would typically be `0x1000000` in x86-64), you *maybe could* get away with it the dylib turns to be **not using** ASLR / PIE , but still that's very likely to break
- legacy `Mach-O` load commands, eventually some might stop being supported by the kernel